# Remove outline/page border in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, border

How do I hide the outside grid lines (at the edges of my data header) in Microsoft Excel?

I need to have gridlines print/view ON for the rest of the data. I can hide some gridlines in my header, by filling the cells with white color, but I cannot get rid of the grid lines on the outside edges (Top Left, Top, Top right). Basically I always have a line/box around my data header.

I have tried changing the line color to white but it does not work. I changed the line color to green. You see a green line on top of a black line. 
Any ideas?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to show *most* of the gridlines but hide some of them. For the lines you don't want to see, try adding a thin line border but set its color to be white (or whatever your background color is).

Answer (score 0):

I have Excel 2010

1. Click on the Office button in the top left corner.
2. Select the Excel Options button at the bottom right side of the Office menu.
3. Select Advanced in the left column.
   *Scroll down to the Display Options for this Worksheet section*.
   *Uncheck the box.*
   *Click OK.*

[image]

Comment: This hides the border but also hides the gridlines